# FlexibleSearch check null params in Report Definitions Hybris

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, flexible-search

I want to make a Report Definitions item in backoffice that will retrieve some columns. The query needs to be like this to retrieve what I need:

```
SELECT {a}, {b} , {c} FROM {model} WHERE {d} IS NULL AND {e} IS NULL
```

All values (a,b...e) are strings. I want to parametrize the **{d}** and **{e}** column, but I want to be able to search exactly the query I write before.
I start to do something like:

```
SELECT {a}, {b}, {c} FROM {model} WHERE {d}=?dStatus AND {e}=?eStatus
```

, and **dStatus** and **eStatus** paramas was **java.lang.String** types, but this didn't work.

It's possible to make this flexibleSearch query with {d} and {e} columns parametrized to search for null values in Report Definitions?

Answer (score 2):

Hi If you want to make a Report Definition parameterized it's Possible.

you can do it via the following steps.

```
<itemtype code="testBasicOrderEntryReport" extends="Item" metatype="ViewType"
                  jaloonly="true" jaloclass="de.hybris.platform.util.ViewResultItem" generate="false">
            <description>Basic Order Entry Report</description>
            <custom-properties>
                <property name="legacyPersistence">
                    <value>java.lang.Boolean.TRUE</value>
                </property>
                <property name="query">
                    <value>
                        " SELECT "
                        + "{BaseStore.name} AS country, "
                        + "{Order.code} AS orderCode, "
                        + "DATE({Order.date}) AS orderDate, "
                        + "{Product.code} AS productCode, "
                        + "{OrderEntry.quantity} AS qty, "
                        + "{OrderMargin.margin} AS CVR "
                        + "FROM { OrderEntry "
                        + "JOIN Order ON {OrderEntry.order} = {Order.pk} "
                        + "JOIN BaseStore ON {Order.store} = {BaseStore.pk} "
                        + "JOIN Product ON {OrderEntry.product} = {Product.pk} "
                        + "LEFT JOIN OrderMargin ON {OrderEntry.margin} = {OrderMargin.pk} "
                        + "} WHERE "
                        + "{Order.store}=?baseStoreParam "
                        + "AND "
                        + "{Order.date}&gt;=?orderStartDateParam "
                        + "AND "
                        + "{Order.date}&lt;=?orderEndDateParam "
                        + "AND "
                        + "{Order.versionID} is null "
                    </value>
                </property>
            </custom-properties>
            <attributes>
                <attribute qualifier="baseStoreParam" type="BaseStore" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
                    <persistence type="jalo"/>
                    <modifiers write="false" search="false" optional="false"/>
                    <custom-properties>
                        <property name="param">
                            <value>Boolean.TRUE</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="position">
                            <value>Integer.valueOf(0)</value>
                        </property>
                    </custom-properties>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="orderStartDateParam" type="java.util.Date" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
                    <persistence type="jalo"/>
                    <modifiers write="false" search="false" optional="false"/>
                    <custom-properties>
                        <property name="param">
                            <value>Boolean.TRUE</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="position">
                            <value>Integer.valueOf(1)</value>
                        </property>
                    </custom-properties>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="orderEndDateParam" type="java.util.Date" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
                    <persistence type="jalo"/>
                    <modifiers write="false" search="false" optional="false"/>
                    <custom-properties>
                        <property name="param">
                            <value>Boolean.TRUE</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="position">
                            <value>Integer.valueOf(2)</value>
                        </property>
                    </custom-properties>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="country" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
                    <persistence type="jalo"/>
                    <modifiers write="false" search="false" optional="false"/>
                    <custom-properties>
                        <property name="param">
                            <value>Boolean.FALSE</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="position">
                            <value>Integer.valueOf(0)</value>
                        </property>
                    </custom-properties>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="orderCode" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
                    <persistence type="jalo"/>
                    <modifiers write="false" search="false" optional="false"/>
                    <custom-properties>
                        <property name="param">
                            <value>Boolean.FALSE</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="position">
                            <value>Integer.valueOf(1)</value>
                        </property>
                    </custom-properties>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="orderDate" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
                    <persistence type="jalo"/>
                    <modifiers write="false" search="false" optional="false"/>
                    <custom-properties>
                        <property name="param">
                            <value>Boolean.FALSE</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="position">
                            <value>Integer.valueOf(2)</value>
                        </property>
                    </custom-properties>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="productCode" type="java.lang.String" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
                    <persistence type="jalo"/>
                    <modifiers write="false" search="false" optional="false"/>
                    <custom-properties>
                        <property name="param">
                            <value>Boolean.FALSE</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="position">
                            <value>Integer.valueOf(3)</value>
                        </property>
                    </custom-properties>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="qty" type="java.lang.Integer" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
                    <persistence type="jalo"/>
                    <modifiers write="false" search="false" optional="false"/>
                    <custom-properties>
                        <property name="param">
                            <value>Boolean.FALSE</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="position">
                            <value>Integer.valueOf(4)</value>
                        </property>
                    </custom-properties>
                </attribute>
                <attribute qualifier="CVR" type="java.lang.Double" metatype="ViewAttributeDescriptor">
                    <persistence type="jalo"/>
                    <modifiers write="false" search="false" optional="false"/>
                    <custom-properties>
                        <property name="param">
                            <value>Boolean.FALSE</value>
                        </property>
                        <property name="position">
                            <value>Integer.valueOf(5)</value>
                        </property>
                    </custom-properties>
                </attribute>
            </attributes>
        </itemtype>
```

Here **baseStoreParam,orderStartDateParam,orderEndDateParam** are parameter.

Note: based on the expected result value and type we need to define the position and type of that attribute in the **`<attributes>`** tag.

Comment: thanks for answer, it it possible to call dynamic attribute handler during param creation. option is there but somehow handler is not being called, I am not sure if I m missing any step. I have added attribute and handler in it., tried with update as well.

Comment: I hope you were missing some modifiers and make write=true in attribute section then define dynamic attribute handler.

Comment: I am creating manually using backoffice and write attribute is not available, may be i can try do the same way with appropriate attribute. To be more precise my requirement is to create param for basestore and put flexible query for result but it is not possible to put flexible query because table does not exist for dynamic attribute and i am thinking if it will work only with handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can split original query and its condition

```
String query = "SELECT {a}, {b}, {c} FROM {model} WHERE {d} %s AND {e} %s";
String dStatusParam = "";
String eStatusParam = "";
if (null == dStatus) {
   dStatusParam = "IS NULL";
} else {
   dStatusParam = "= '" + dStatus + "'";
}
if (null == eStatus) {
   eStatusParam = "IS NULL";
} else {
   eStatusParam = "= '" + eStatus + "'";
}
query = String.format(query, dStatusParam, eStatusParam);
```